# Issue with SQLite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm creating an application. I have two forms. One form has an `EditText` and a `Spinner`. The other form is for viewing the database. I know about `SQLiteOpenHelper` and `SQLiteDatabase`, but I am having connection issues. I can't see the output from the database. Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

Comment: If only you added some code and maybe someone would've answered your question ..

Answer (score 2):

Go through the Notepad Tutorial

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html